# Echo en MVC ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas, estoy tratando de llamar a un método de un controller a una vista, esto trabajando en MVC ASP. El detalle es que necesito que lo que tenga en esa función me lo imprima en la vista; en PHP con solamente colocar un echo después de una función me lo imprime, por ejemplo Echo $roles->zonaName($row['idUser']); pero en MVC no tengo idea. El siguiente es el método que tengo en el controller:

```
public void InnerJoinTratamientos(int id) {

   _CD.InnerJoinTratamientos(id);

}
```

y en el view lo estoy llamando así:

```
<td>

@{ Response.Write(_tr.InnerJoinTratamientos(item.idTratamiento))}

</td>
```

la instancia está hecha y todo lo demás. 
Gracias por la ayuda de antemano! espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: El controller que tienes no regresa nada debe regresar el modelo que definiste en tu view return View(tuModelo) y en la vista hacer eferencia al modelo @Model.propiedad, mejor sube el código completo de tu controller y del view

Answer (score 0):

La forma más simple y básica de hacer lo que quieres sería utilizando el objeto `ViewBag` de la siguiente manera:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Mostrar();
    return View();
}

public void Mostrar()
{
    ViewBag.title = "Index";
 }
```

y en tu vista...

```
@ViewBag.Title
```

Ahora existen un sin fin de maneras de realizar lo mismo, pero sin más detalle no te podemos ayudar de mejor manera.